# Unable to identify the Colon key in Mobile Keyboard

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keyboard-events

I have a key down event handler and I'm having a hard time attempting to identify if the user pressed a colon in a mobile phone keypad (e.g. iPhone)

The problem is that the browser returns the same `event.keyCode` value (or `event.which`, depending on browser)  for both colons and semi-colons.And since at the time the `keydown` event handler fires, the value hasn't been added to the `HTMLInputElement's` `value` attribute, I am not able to use a simple get-the-last-character-and-check-if-its-a-colon logic.

And using the `String.fromCharCode()` for 186 (which is the `event.which` value for the colon button on the iPhone) does not give me a semi-colon but a weird circle character. But printing
`String.fromCharCode(59)` *does* give me a colon.

Here is a simple version of my code:

```
isColon : function(event)
                {
                    // first check for desktop browsers 
                    if (event.shiftKey && event.which == constants.KEYS.COLON) //the constant is 186 or 59 depending on browser, this works on all desktop browsers
                        return true;
                    //this doesnt work as event.which=186 which is NOT giving a ":"  when I say String.fromCharCode(event.which)
                    if (String.fromCharCode(event.which) == ":")
                        return true;
                    return false;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

use keypress instead; you can still event.preventDefault() to prevent the character from appearing in the input.

Comment: keypress isnt standard.
From the jQuery site:"the keypress event isn't covered by any official specification, the actual behavior encountered when using it may differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms."

http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Comment: while not a standard, there's a good deal of support, especially in the mobile browsers I have tested it against.

ppk has a brief compatibility table at http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html